# Flex/Flash Flipbook using PDF file

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, pdf, actionscript

I want to create Flipbook in flex/Flash. Normally its created via XML and XML has some image or swf list it is loading as page in flipbook. But I want to create this functionality directly from the PDF file. Just developer need to give only PDF file name/path flip book will generate automatically.

Can you help me for the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PDF files are generally very complex to work with, the ever-expanding set of features makes it practically infeasible to write a library for as3 that would load and display any arbitrary PDF file.

The way most flipbook applications go about this is to render the pdf pages to images (or in some cases images with vector features) server-side or in an author environment using sophisticated PDF rendering engines. The images are then loaded and displayed by the Flash/Flex application leaving only the interaction part of the flip book to the client-side.